# update() function disregards limit() in mongo

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, mongoengine

Lets say I have a 10 documents of `Item` in the database.

Lets retrieve 3 documents of Item matching some condition using limit().

`documents = Item.objects(somefield=somecondition).limit(3)`

Now if I do

`documents.update()`, mongoengine updates all the documents in the database matched by the query not just the 3 documents I have limited my query to.

I also tried setting `multi=False` in the params, but then only one document gets updated.

Is there anyway to do update while querying itself instead of looping over the documents one by one?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no available solution to your problem provided by MongoDB. However you could try something like this

```
documents.forEach(
    function (e) {
        e.field = 'value';
        db.collection.save(e);
    }
);
```